# Regular Expressions Java Pattern

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

```
String search="firstName:john doe,";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w+?)(:|<|>|=)(\\w+?),");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(search+",");
while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); //firstName
        System.out.println(matcher.group(2)); //:
        System.out.println(matcher.group(3)); //john   

    }
```

I want a regex to match  string  john doe  which contains spaces in group 3 :

Comment: replace the last (\\w+?) with ([\\w]+ [\\w]+?). I am assuming the name does not have a middle name. its only firstname lastname

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming comma is the marker for the end of the name we can try this:

```
String search="firstName:john doe,";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)(:|<|>|=)([^,]+),");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(search);
```